# Optimization Ruby on Rails (count)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, counter

How is it possible to optimize this code? (

(Many messages)

```
    def messages_count
      total = 0
      users.each do |u|
        total += u.messages.size
      end
    total
    end
```

Thanks you

Comment: Use [`counter_cache`](http://yerb.net/blog/2014/03/13/three-easy-steps-to-using-counter-caches-in-rails/) .

Comment: The question is ambiguous. Simplest answer is `Message.all.count`

Comment: yes @GregDan is right

Comment: Ahha, `Message.all.count` is wrong, because `users` have messages and `admin` have messages, but thx @ArupRakshit

Comment: @BorisBresciani: counter_cache and `Message.count` are two very different things. counter_cache is the best solution here.

Comment: Yes, thanks you @SergioTulentsev

Answer (score 0):

As I'm assuming that there is a modal `User` associated with `has_many :messages` `Message` modal.
 `users = User.created_after(3.days.ago)` or something
You can use in a single line query

```
Message.where("user_id IN (?)",users.pluck(:id)).count
```

or

```
Message.where(user: users).count
```

Comment: You assume that `users` represent all of the users. Which is not necessarily true. For all we know, it can be `users = User.created_after(3.days.ago)` or something

Comment: yes ofcourse  users will contain users you want from db and query can be fired, no worries about that...

Comment: In this case, `Message.all.count` is a wrong solution. Can be just `Message.count`, btw.

Comment: yes you are right but I mentioned any case for that

Comment: You missed the point. It's not enough for message to not have empty user_id. You also need to count only the needed user ids. And not count not needed.

Comment: `Message.where(user: users).count` should be equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write it as:

```
def messages_count
  users.sum { |u| u.messages.size }
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
def messages_count
  total = users.inject(0) {|result,user| result + user.messages.size}
end
```

In your case, eventually you are counting all the messages. So you could use

```
Message.count
```

Comment: How is it more optimized (the inject)?

Comment: Also, your assumption ("you are counting all the messages") is based on nothing.

Comment: In this case of inject , we do only one iteration over an array without any hard calculation within the iterator.

Comment: "we do only one iteration over an array without any hard calculation within the iterator" - so does the original code.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It's more "optimized" in the sense of less code :)

Comment: @Зелёный look at the question. Its about optimizing ROR code.

Comment: ROR also inludes `html`, `css`, `js`, `c` and `assembler` code.